# Optimizing / cleaning up code for a broader BFS of game states

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, breadth-first-search

TDLR: I want to find ways to have my code run faster.

I have created some code that can be given a start state for a game. Then run though every option to find the one that ends with the best score. However there are ~15 actions in this game and each increases the search space by anywhere from x5 to x30. Currently I limit the search by evaluation each state after an action and only use the top x ones. However this has potential to cut out good strategies. For example in some cases it is better to Buy then sell the first days as you would make more money then just getting a trader for +20 gold each day. I want to find ways to allow for a greater search space with my limited time and hardware.

First I cleaned up the data structures and tried to make simple operations faster. From there I added ProcessPoolExecutor to allow for parrel processing.
Now when using cProfile it seems dataclasses replace is the function that takes the most time. I am unsure if there is a better way to copy the data, if it should be frozen or unfrozen, and other possible optimization. cProfile also says that string creation is the 2nd time suck.

The Game: In this game You pick a Town. This sets your starting start. From there you are (normally) given 15 days to try and achieve the most amount of money you can. Each day you can make one action. If wanted I can link the google playstore so people can have a better idea

Code sample:

```
from os import system
from enum import IntEnum
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from more_itertools import divide as m_iter_divide
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, replace as dcReplace
clear: () = lambda: system('cls')
import cProfile

class AI:
    def __init__(self, limit=10000, town='Normalia', with_merch=False, with_witch=False, que=None):
        self.game = Game(with_merch, with_witch)
        self.start_player = Player()
        self.game_array = []  # Wrap the game in what town you want to use
        self.finished_array = []
        self.town_effect(town)
        self.limit = limit
        if que is not None:
            self.start_player = self.game.game_loop(self.start_player, que)
        self.game_array.append(self.start_player)

    def find_solve_pool(self):
        day = self.game_array[0].day
        seen = set()
        while True:
            if len(self.game_array) == 0:
                break

            self.game_array.sort(key=lambda x: self.game.check__points(x), reverse=True)
            self.game_array = self.game_array[0:self.limit]

            day += 1
            print(f'Processing Day {day} - #{len(self.game_array)}')

            current_states = self.game_array
            self.game_array = []

            with ProcessPoolExecutor(6) as executor:
                result = list(executor.map(self.execute_events, [list(c) for c in m_iter_divide(6, current_states)]))
            for [reprocess, solved] in result:
                for player in reprocess:
                    if hash(player) not in seen:
                        self.game_array.append(player)
                        seen.add(hash(player))
                for item in solved:
                    self.finished_array.append(item)

        self.print_solves()

    def find_solve_loop(self):
        day = self.game_array[0].day
        while True:
            if len(self.game_array) == 0:
                break

            self.game_array.sort(key=lambda x: self.game.check__points(x), reverse=True)
            self.game_array = self.game_array[0:self.limit]

            day += 1
            print(f'Processing Day {day} - #{len(self.game_array)}')

            current_states = self.game_array
            self.game_array = []

            result = self.execute_events(current_states)

            reprocess, solved = result
            for player in reprocess:
                self.game_array.append(player)
            for item in solved:
                self.finished_array.append(item)

        self.print_solves()

    def execute_events(self, to_process):
        hold = [[], []]
        reprocess = 0
        solved = 1
        while len(to_process) > 0:
            # Copy and delete what we are working with
            current: Player = to_process.pop()

            if self.game.merch_on and current.merchant_happened is False and (current.day + 1 in self.game.merch_days or self.game.merch_days == -1):
                for [action, cost] in merchant_event_list:
                    if current.gold >= cost * (25 - (5 * self.game.merch_discount)):
                        merch_event = self.game.event_merchant(current, action)
                        to_process.append(merch_event)

            if self.game.witch_on and current.witch_happened is False and (current.day + 1 in self.game.witch_days or self.game.witch_days == -1):
                for action in witch_event_list:
                    witch_event = self.game.event_witch(current, action)
                    to_process.append(witch_event)

            current = self.game.start_of_day(current)
            if current.gold < 0:
                # print('Starved to death: ' + path[-1])
                continue

            # Make all options
            # TODO - Logic for witch and merchant will just append
            if current.day < current.max_day and current.bought_last is False:
                days_left = current.max_day - current.day
                food_multi = 2 if days_left > 1 else 0
                current_cost = self.game.check__food_cost(current)
                max_food = min(current.gold // self.game.item_shop['Food'][Store.BUY], self.game.check__weight_left(current) // self.game.item_shop['Food'][Store.WEIGHT])

                # THIS IS AN ALT THAT I DON"T THINK IS THAT MUCH BETTER
                # options = set()
                # day_needs = [current_cost*2, current_cost*2+1]
                # next_day_needs = []
                # for i in range(days_left):
                #     if len(day_needs) == 0:
                #         break
                #     for need in day_needs:
                #         if max_food >= need > current.food:
                #            options.add(need - current.food)
                #             for l in range(i):
                #                 next_day_needs.append(need+current_cost+l)

                needed_food = max(0, food_multi * current_cost - current.food)
                # Buy Items -- Everything
                for i in range(needed_food, max_food+1):
                    to_buy = self.game.check__find_buy(current, i)
                    new_action = [f'Buy - {to_buy}']
                    buy_everything = self.game.event_buy_items(current, *to_buy)
                    buy_everything = self.game.end_of_day(buy_everything, new_action)
                    hold[reprocess].append(buy_everything)

                # Buy Items -- only Food
                needed_food = max(1, food_multi*current_cost - current.food)
                for i in range(needed_food, max_food+1):
                    to_buy = self.game.check__find_buy(current, i, True)
                    new_action = [f'Buy - {to_buy}']
                    buy_only_food = self.game.event_buy_items(current, *to_buy)
                    buy_only_food = self.game.end_of_day(buy_only_food, new_action)
                    hold[reprocess].append(buy_only_food)

            if current.day == current.max_day or current.food >= self.game.check__food_cost(current):
                # Sell Items
                if self.game.check__has_items(current):
                    new_action = ['Sell']
                    sell = self.game.event_sell_items(current)
                    sell = self.game.end_of_day(sell, new_action)
                    if sell.day < sell.max_day:
                        hold[reprocess].append(sell)
                    else:
                        hold[solved].append(sell)

                # Buy Trader
                if current.gold >= 25 and (current.day == current.max_day or current.food >= self.game.check__food_cost(current) + (not current.oasis_of_sanctifan) * self.game.npc['Trader'][NPC.EAT]):
                    new_action = ['Trader']
                    buy_trader = self.game.event_buy_npc(current, 'Trader')
                    buy_trader = self.game.end_of_day(buy_trader, new_action)
                    if buy_trader.day < buy_trader.max_day:
                        hold[reprocess].append(buy_trader)
                    else:
                        hold[solved].append(buy_trader)

                # Buy Camel
                if current.gold >= 30 and (current.day == current.max_day or current.food >= self.game.check__food_cost(current) + (not current.oasis_of_sanctifan) * (self.game.npc['Camel'][NPC.EAT] + current.camelization)):
                    new_action = ['Camel']
                    buy_camel = self.game.event_buy_npc(current, 'Camel')
                    buy_camel = self.game.end_of_day(buy_camel, new_action)
                    if buy_camel.day < buy_camel.max_day:
                        hold[reprocess].append(buy_camel)
                    else:
                        hold[solved].append(buy_camel)

                # Interest
                if current.interest_rate > 1.2 or current.day == current.max_day:
                    new_action = ['Interest']
                    interest = self.game.event_interest(current)
                    interest = self.game.end_of_day(interest, new_action)
                    if interest.day < interest.max_day:
                        hold[reprocess].append(interest)
                    else:
                        hold[solved].append(interest)

            if len(hold[solved]) >= 1000:
                hold[solved].sort(key=lambda x: self.game.check__points(x), reverse=True)
                hold[solved] = hold[1][0:10]
        return hold

    def print_solves(self):
        print(f'Printing Solves')
        self.finished_array.sort(key=lambda x: self.game.check__points(x), reverse=True)
        for i in range(10):
            print(f'Place {i + 1}: {self.game.check__points(self.finished_array[i])} points')
            print(self.finished_array[i])
            print(self.finished_array[i].actions)
            print("")

    def town_effect(self, town):
        match town:
            case 'Normalia':
                pass
            case 'Fang_Mo':
                self.start_player = dcReplace(self.start_player, pottery=self.start_player.pottery + 1)
            case 'L_Exquise':
                self.game.npc['Trader'][NPC.EAT] = 0
            case 'Mahaji':
                self.game.item_shop['Spice'][Store.SELL] += 5
            case 'Tocaccialli':
                self.start_player = dcReplace(self.start_player, max_day=self.start_player.max_day + 1)
            case 'Bajaar':
                self.game.npc['Trader'][NPC.EFFECT] += 20
            case 'Doba_Lao':
                self.start_player = dcReplace(self.start_player, interest_rate=self.start_player.interest_rate + 0.2)
            case 'Huangoz':
                self.game.item_shop['Marble'][Store.BUY] -= 20
            case 'Port_Willam':
                self.start_player = dcReplace(self.start_player, backpack=self.start_player.backpack + 15)
            case 'Moonin':
                self.game.merch_days = -1
            case 'Cornecopea':
                self.game.item_shop['Food'][Store.BUY] = 0
            case 'Eduming':
                self.game.trader_interest = True
            case 'Octoyashi':
                self.start_player = dcReplace(self.start_player, food=self.start_player.food + 3)
            case 'Kifuai':
                self.start_player = dcReplace(self.start_player, gold=self.start_player.gold + 10)
            case 'Skjollird':
                self.game.npc['Camel'][NPC.BUY] += 10
                self.game.npc['Camel'][NPC.EFFECT] += 10
            case 'Petrinov':
                self.start_player = dcReplace(self.start_player, set_interest=True)
            case 'Jilliqo':
                self.game.daily_income += 10
            case 'Gayawaku':
                self.game.item_shop['Food'][Store.WEIGHT] = 0
            case 'Vilparino':
                self.game.merch_discount = True
            case 'Sanctifan':
                self.start_player = dcReplace(self.start_player, one_free_interest=True)
            case 'Mehaz':
                self.game.npc['Camel'][NPC.EAT] = 0
            case 'Ipartus':
                self.game.item_shop['Silk'][Store.BUY] -= 100


if __name__ == '__main__':
    que = [
        ['Trader'],
        ['Trader'],
        ['Trader'],
        ['Camel']
    ]
    que = None
    solver = AI(town=town_list[4], limit=10000, with_merch=True, with_witch=False, que=que)
    cProfile.run('solver.find_solve_pool()')
    # Loop Time: 128
    # Pool Time: 114
```

Full Code: https://github.com/JayMcArthur/Trading-Caravan-Solver